# PHP web app, selecting from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have database for books and authors. the relationship between these two entities is many to many so there's a joint table between them.

1. `books` has `books.book_id` as primary, `authors.author_id` as primary and the joint table `book_authors` has: `book_authors.book_id` and `book_authors.author_id`.
2. Each book has more than one author.

What I am trying to do is to have a php page that shows each book in one line then under, it says: author1:...., author2 (if applicable).

I want my php to look somewhat like:

```
Book Name: THE BOOK NAME
Author(s): joe- John- Sara
```

I used the following code and the problem is that it returns with single results. So if book1 is authored by author1 and author2, I am only getting one author in the result page. Here's my code I used.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","yalmuza","e6ddthmu");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("yalmuza", $con);

$result1 = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        books.title, authors.fname, authors.lname
    FROM
        books, book_authors, authors
    WHERE
        books.book_id = book_authors.book_id
        AND authors.author_id=book_authors.author_id
    GROUP BY
        books.book_id
");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
  {
print "<h3>Book Name:</h3>";
  echo $row ['title'];
print "<br />";
print "Author(s):";
  echo $row ['fname'];
  echo $row ['lname'];
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the code you tried. Here we don't really give canned solutions, but help with the one you have.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It sounds like you need to look at  PHP and  HTML basics, maybe work through a book or tutorial. We expect questions to be specific and answerable, requests for tutorials, lengthy walkthroughs and codewriting are explicitly off topic.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's sounds database need to learn and ACID.

Comment: i tried this mysql query and it worked fine but the problem is that it shows redundant results:
select books.title, authors.fname, authors.lname from books, authors, book_authors where book_authors.book_id=books.book_id and book_authors.author_id=authors.author_id order by books.title;"

Comment: I mean: results i get like:
book1 - author
book1(again) - author

I need an array of authors and my php code was not working at all. I used basic code from w3schools and didnt work

Comment: @YousifAlmuzayen - great, glad you tried something. Please edit your SQL query into your question before more people vote to close - at the moment it looks like you've not tried anything!

Comment: @halfer Thanks. I just added the whole php code I used. Could you take a look at it and let me know if you have any ideas or suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It looks OK to me. Does it run? If so, then it's just your SQL statement you need to work on.

Comment: I've reformatted your query also. Although it may not be the right query, try to write your SQL like this - upper case statements, lower case objects. With word wrapping, it is much more readable for both you and us.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT books.* GROUP_CONCAT(author.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS authors
RIGHT JOIN book_authors ON books.id = book_author.book_id
LEFT JOIN author ON book_author.author_id = author.id
GROUP BY book.id
```

You can read the manual on how to execute a MySQL query:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: What is the php code I should insert this into to get a simple result page? Thanks

Comment: @YousifAlmuzayen, try `mysql_query()` or `PDO` to make this query from your php page.

Comment: @HamzaWaqas i'm sorry but i am just a beginner in php. could you provide me with basic php code for that page including the for or while loop that will make it work. Thanks

Comment: @YousifAlmuzayen - if you are a total beginner, you should be doing tutorials, not asking people to write your code for you! The ethos of this site is strongly "ask for help on things you have actually tried" `:)`